# 403 (Forbidden) Error for a specific image

Tags: php, html, permissions, xampp

SOLVED: set specific file permissions of 'logo.png' to 755.

I am getting a 403 (Forbidden) error for a specific image on my site. Other images are working fine and they are located in exactly the same place.

The only differences between this image and the others are that this image is a 'png' and the others are jpg. It's also copied from a shared Google Drive folder. I don't see how that could upset anything, but I can't find any other differences.

I'm using localhost to test the site - it's built mostly in HTML and PHP and I'm using XAMPP. I've tried altering permissions for my Assets folder in Htdocs but it doesn't help.

It's just strange that it's once specific image.

Any advice? Code below.

Working:

```
    <img src="/assets/images/logo.jpg" alt="site logo">
```

Broken:

```
    <img src="/assets/images/logo.png" alt="site logo">
```

Comment: Why won't you just convert the picture into jpg? There is a plenty of freeware to do so.

Comment: does `logo.png`  exist and have read permissions for `apache`?

Comment: What does your http servers error log file say?

Comment: Please check if there are any rewriting rules that apply based on the naming pattern.

Comment: thank you - the error log said 'AH00132: file permissions deny server access'. I hadn't thought of setting the image itself with 755 permissions. @arkascha what do you mean by rewriting rules?

Comment: You never need a file permission of `755` for an image! How do you want to _execute_ an image?

Comment: Rewriting rules are a feature of http servers to "reinterpret" incoming requests to map (virtual) URLs to respondable resources. Check the documentation of apaches rewriting module for that. It is one of the basic techologies in web stuff.

Comment: @arkascha that seemed to solve my issue! The image now appears fine

Comment: Certainly it does if this was a file permission issue (as the log file message says). But `644` would be the correct permissions for an image.